# Cancer patient travels back in time to WW2 to prevent the development of a cure for cancer

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for the name of a story about a time traveler who goes back to WW2 England to prevent the development of a cure for cancer. The traveler is a well known cancer patient, who appears at a clinic where a doctor has made a breakthrough discovery that will lead to a cure for cancer. The doctor does not even know the implications of his discovery yet, and the traveler eventually morphs himself into a bomb and blows up the doctor, himself, and the lab.

Comment: Does [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64670/i-need-help-identifying-a-short-science-fiction-story-about-cancer-as-human-evol) answer your question?

Comment: And then slowly reconstitutes himself.  I've read this one recently but can't remember the title or author.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - based on our [meta consensus](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/39144) both of the answers need be accepted in order for one question to be closed as a dupe

Comment: Marked to re-open since there is no indication of acceptance here.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's been asked and answered.

[I need help identifying a short science fiction story about cancer as human evolution](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64670/i-need-help-identifying-a-short-science-fiction-story-about-cancer-as-human-evol?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Think I read it in the Conklin anthology.